# Token Generator Using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class that I am using to generate 10 character alphanumeric 'tokens' (Strings) and writing them to a txt file.

I would like to be able to generate as many as possible as quickly as possible without producing any duplicates. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Random;

public class TokenGenerator  {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (;;) {
         getSaltString();
    }
 }

public static void getSaltString() {
    String SALTCHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    StringBuilder salt = new StringBuilder();
    Random rnd = new Random();

    while (salt.length() < 10) { // length of the random string.
        int index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * SALTCHARS.length());
        salt.append(SALTCHARS.charAt(index));
    }
    String saltStr = salt.toString();
    writer(saltStr);
}

public static void writer(String code) {
    try {
        File file = new File("codes.txt");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true)));
        out.println(code);
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("Dead");
    }
  }
}
```

I was wondering,

A: Is this an efficient way of generating the tokens?

B: How can I call this method using threads to generate them faster

Answer (score 1):

### Bug 1

Requirement is 'without producing any duplicates'. You have not *exactly* implemented this (although the chances of happening are really small)

### Bug 2

You have no condition of exiting. The program will run forever, and might have inconsistent behaviour if you terminate it externally.

### A: Is this an efficient way of generating the tokens?

It can be more efficient.

- You can keep the `File` and `Writers` open instead of opening each time.
- You can reuse the `new Random()` instead of creating one each time, or..
- ...use `int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);`
- You can use a fixed for loop instead of checking the `salt.length()`.

Also use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

### B: How can I call this method using threads to generate them faster

As you write to file, this process will finally be I/O bound, so there is probably no real gain from multi-threading.